# Chartboost with Unity 5 on xcode missing linking file

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, chartboost

Has anybody used chatboost with unity 5 on IOS? I get a linking error and a warning
warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/alexm/Downloads/iosFree/LibrariesPlugins/iOS'

ld: library not found for -lChartboost

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

On the Android everything is fine. Do I have to do anything extra other what i mentioned on chartboost integration page?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if the Chartboost plugin is using some PostprocessBuildPlayer stuff, that is isn't getting clobbered by a different script.

If, in XCode, you check the build phases tab for linked frameworks and you don't see Chartboost.framework, it's likely the build script not running correctly.